# Finding the number of areas of true values in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a question about my homework in scratching my head-on.
So I need to build a program that counts the number of areas of true value (near to each other) in the 2D array.

```java
{0,1,0,0}
{1,0,0,1}
{1,1,0,1}
{1,0,0,1}
```

So the program needs to return `3` because there `3` places with trues.
If there are no true then to return 0.
The program needs to recursive and without loops.
Thanks in advance to the ones that will help me solve this one. I didn't even have any idea how to start it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you do a `dfs` to record the cells you went and you can have a `boolean[][]` to record the cells you went. Then you just loop through the grid to see where you have not gone. If you did not go there yet, go there and also perform a `dfs` on nearby cells, but anyway, a code would be more clear.

```java
public static int[][] grid;
public static boolean[][] went;
public static int r, c;

public static void dfs(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= r || y < 0 || y >= c) {//out of the grid
        return;
    }

    if (went[x][y]) {//I went here
        return;
    }
    went[x][y] = true;

    if (grid[x][y] == 0) {//It's false here so don't go
        return;
    }
    dfs(x - 1, y);
    dfs(x + 1, y);
    dfs(x, y - 1);
    dfs(x, y + 1);
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input.readLine());

    //input reading
    r = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    c = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

    grid = new int[r][c];
    went = new boolean[r][c];

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        st = new StringTokenizer(input.readLine());
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }
    }
    //end of input reading
    int cnt = 0;//number of areas
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            // If I have not went have and the value
            // must be true so I would perform a dfs
            // (since I only care about the value of 1s)
            if (!went[i][j] && grid[i][j] == 1) {
                cnt++;//add to our counter
                dfs(i, j);//have not went here
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cnt);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I need to do that without loops at all

Comment: @MichaelBaazov So not even one loop? Then how do you read the input? Or is the input given to you(as an varible)?

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the only recursion. No loops.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(countTrueAreas(new int[][] {
            { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
            { 1, 0, 0, 1 },
            { 1, 1, 0, 1 },
            { 1, 0, 0, 1 } }));  // 3
}

public static int countTrueAreas(int[][] grid) {
    return countTrueAreas(grid, 0, 0, 10) - 10;
}

private static int countTrueAreas(int[][] grid, int row, int col, int num) {
    if (row == grid.length)
        return num;
    if (col == grid[row].length) {
        if (++row == grid.length)
            return num;
        col = 0;
    }

    if (grid[row][col] == 1)
        dfs(grid, row, col, num++);

    return countTrueAreas(grid, row, col + 1, num);
}

private static void dfs(int[][] grid, int row, int col, int num) {
    if (row < 0 || row >= grid.length)
        return;
    if (col < 0 || col >= grid[row].length)
        return;
    if (grid[row][col] != 1)
        return;

    grid[row][col] = num;
    dfs(grid, row, col - 1, num);
    dfs(grid, row, col + 1, num);
    dfs(grid, row - 1, col, num);
    dfs(grid, row + 1, col, num);
}
```